# Understanding Javascript return statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen the code below and am not quite sure what's going on.  There is no return type set on in the function, so I can't figure out what ORing 3 strings will do.  What will this method return and what does the OR do?

```
 return $scope.filterLabels[key] ||
                $scope.filterLabels[oldSchoolFacetCode()] ||
                key;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `||` operator returns the left argument if it is truthy, the right one otherwise.

For example, `null || false` evaluates to `false`, whereas `false || null` is `null`.

With this in mind, the `return` statement will return:

- `$scope.filterLabels[key]` if it is truthy
- `$scope.filterLabels[oldSchoolFacetCode()]` if the first is falsy and this is truthy
- `key` if neither of the above have been returned yet.

The code is effectively shorthand for:

```
if( $scope.filterLabels[key]) return $scope.filterLabels[key];
if( $scope.filterLabels[oldSchoolFacetCode()]) return $scope.filterLabels[oldSchoolFacetCode()];
return key;
```

Comment: what it would return if all the values are not truthy..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Whatever non-truthy value `key` has.

Answer (score 4):

If the operand in the left of the || operand is truthy, it will return that operand (left side), if it falsy it will return the right side operand.

A simpler scenario would be one like this..

```
return true || false; // this would return true

return false || true; // this would also return true

return false || 3; // this would return 3

return 3 || 7; // this would also return 3
```

In this specific case, this would mean...

```
return a || b || c;
```

- if a is true, it will return true.
- if a is false, it will evaluate the next expression, meaning..

  - if b is truthy, it will return b
  - if b is falsy, it will return c (even if c is falsy)

The falsy values:

- `false`
- `0` (zero)
- `""` or `''` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN` (Not-a-Number)

Comment: Oh praise [Brendan Eich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich) for [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). I couldn't live without it! ([a blog about it](https://www.echoditto.com/blog/short-circuit-evaluation-javascript-or-ternary-operator-binary))

Answer (score 1):

If any of the items are true, the || operator will return the first item that evaluates to true (== not ===)

```
return "" || "foo" || "bar"
```

returns "foo"

Answer (score 0):

The above statement would return a valid value meaning not `null`/defined etc... and it will validate from left to right.

Consider this scenario,

```
return a || b || c;
```

Now if `a` and `b` are `undefined`, in this context it would return the value of `c`.

Comment: Yes, if by "valid value" you mean truthy, i.e. something that `== true`.

Comment: @Juhana Yeah you got it.. :)